# Moving a file into a subfolder in C# trouble?

Tags: c#, visual-c#-express-2010

For some reason, the user that installs this, when they click the button, nothing happens. Also, if i take the try and catch, it says the file already exists, and it does not. The sub folder does, but not the file. What is wrong? Here is my code:

```
            string pathUser4 = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
            string pathDownload4 = (pathUser4 + @"\Downloads\");
            string sourceFile = pathDownload4 + listBox1.Text;

            string pathdoc5 = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
            string pathDownload5 = (pathdoc5 + @"\iracing\setups\");
            string destinationFile = pathDownload5 + comboBox1.Text;

            File.Move(sourceFile, destinationFile);
        }
        catch { }
            if (comboBox1.Text == "Select File Destination")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Select A Destination Folder", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
```

Comment: For coding style, use Path.Combine to create path's.
`string pathDownload4 = Path.Combine(pathUser4, "Downloads");`

Comment: Make sure that `comboBox1.Text` is a *FileName*

Comment: that does not work for some reason. It gives me the wrong directory, and cancels out the user profile for some reason....that is not what is wrong...i know that

Comment: I know that it's not the wrong part, just for better coding style.
Do not use slashes when working with Path.Combine, I think. (so your @"\Downloads\" becomes just "Downloads")

Comment: it add a subfoldername, such as C:\users\BOB\iracing\setups\ + "racecar"

Comment: Here's the info with the slashes on the second parameter: http://coolthingoftheday.blogspot.com/2008/02/pathcombine-be-aware-of-slash-in-second.html

Comment: Can you try giving it a filename? like:
`string destinationFile = pathDownload5 + comboBox1.Text + @"\" + listBox1.Text;`

Comment: i used a breakpoint, and looked at the values and they are good. Also, does it matter if it looks like this: C:\\Users\\Bob\\...

Comment: That does not matter and is expected, yes.

Comment: ok, the source file is like this C:\users\bob\downloads\ + listbox text. Then the destination file is C:\users\bob\documents\iracing\setups\ + combobox.text

Comment: At the time of the File.Move call, what is the value of `sourceFile` and `destinationFile` ?

Comment: it depends on what the user selects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your first problem is your checking the comboBox1.Text for a proper value AFTER you've attempted to move the file.

Second use the Path object as MichelZ suggested.  It's easier and should not cause any issue.

Here is what your code would like with the changes:

```
        // TODO: check for listBox1.Text to be blank or non-file

        if (comboBox1.Text == "Select File Destination")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Select A Destination Folder", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

        string sourceFile = Path.Combine(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile, "Downloads", listBox1.Text;
        string destinationFile = Path.Combine(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments, "iracing", "setups", comboBox1.Text;
        File.Move(sourceFile, destinationFile);
    }
    catch { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you *verifying* the content of variables `sourceFile` and `destinationFile` (via debug), or assuming the combination is working as you'd expect?

Also, please tell me that you're well aware of the injection risks posed by this implementation, and that you're ensuring careful validation of the `listBox1` and `comboBox1` values.

Comment: yes, i am guessing...but i have a friend installing the software and testing it

Comment: Don't guess, _validate_. Are you free to deploy a modified version? Write values to log files, or back to the page if you have to, just find out for _certain_ what these values are.

Answer (score 0):

First, the name for a file and directory in the same directory can not be exactly the same.
In Windows, the name of directory and file is not a separate attribute.
Your comment gave me a hint of that. Hence the exception you got from .NET is accurate.

The issue is not related to having the try-catch block, seems you're blaming it. It's always a good idea to know your errors.

One coding method is to check for file/directory existence before File.Move, an old fashion method :)

Comment: well, it is saying that the file is already there, but it is not.

Comment: But the name for the directory is the same as your file. Sorry I was not clear on that. "names of directory and file are not distinct", per my statement.

Comment: This is a limitation of Windows system, even from DOS 3.1 days, long before you lived maybe, hehe.

Answer (score 0):

To understand where is the problem before of  File.Move It could be useful

> Debug.Assert(!File.Exists(destinationFile),String.Format("file already exists:{0}",destinationFile))

If you can't debug, you could show a MessageBox with an equivalent purpose

Comment: Just before the line were you call the File.Move

Comment: It require System.Diagnostics and to run the program in Debug mode